# How to prevent unnecessary re-renders with React Hooks, function components and function depending on item list

Tags: reactjs

### List of items to render

Given a list of items (coming from the server):

```
const itemsFromServer = {
  "1": {
    id: "1",
    value: "test"
  },
  "2": {
    id: "2",
    value: "another row"
  }
};
```

### Function component for each item

We want to render each item, but only when necessary and something changes:

```
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ id, value, onChange, onSave }) {
  console.log("render", id);

  return (
    <li>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={event => onChange(id, event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => onSave(id)}>Save</button>
    </li>
  );
});
```

### ItemList function component with a `handleSave` function that needs to be memoized.

And there is a possibility to save each individual item:

```
function ItemList() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(itemsFromServer);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    function handleChange(id, value) {
      setItems(currentItems => {
        return {
          ...currentItems,
          [id]: {
            ...currentItems[id],
            value
          }
        };
      });
    },
    [setItems]
  );

  async function handleSave(id) {
    const item = items[id];

    if (item.value.length < 5) {
      alert("Incorrect length.");
      return;
    }

    await save(item);

    alert("Save done :)");
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.values(items).map(item => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          value={item.value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onSave={handleSave}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

How to prevent unnecessary re-renders of each `Item` when only one item changes?

Currently on each render a new `handleSave` function is created. When using `useCallback` the `items` object is included in the dependency list.

### Possible solutions

1. Pass `value` as parameter to `handleSave`, thus removing the `items` object from the dependency list of `handleSave`. In this example that would be a decent solution, but for multiple reasons it's not preferred in the real life scenario (eg. lots more parameters etc.).
2. Use a separate component `ItemWrapper` where the `handleSave` function can be memoized.

```
function ItemWrapper({ item, onChange, onSave }) {
  const memoizedOnSave = useCallback(onSave, [item]);

  return (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      value={item.value}
      onChange={onChange}
      onSave={memoizedOnSave}
    />
  );
}
```

3. With the `useRef()` hook, on each change to `items` write it to the ref and read `items` from  the ref inside the `handleSave` function.
4. Keep a variable `idToSave` in the state. Set this on save. Then trigger the save function with `useEffect(() => { /* save */ }, [idToSave])`. "Reactively".

### Question

All of the solutions above seem not ideal to me. **Are there any other ways to prevent creating a new `handleSave` function on each render for each `Item`, thus preventing unnecessary re-renders?** If not, is there a preferred way to do this?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tesla-9wcph?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gained some new insights (thanks Dan), and I think I prefer something like this below. Sure it might look a bit complicated for such a simple hello world example, but for real world examples it might be a good fit.

Main changes:

- Use a reducer + dispatch for keeping state. Not required, but to make it complete. Then we don't need useCallback for the `onChange` handler.
- Pass down dispatch via context. Not required, but to make it complete. Otherwise just pass down dispatch.
- Use an `ItemWrapper` (or Container) component. Adds an additional component to the tree, but provides value as the structure grows. It also reflects the situation we have: each item has a save functionality that requires the entire item. But the `Item` component itself does not. `ItemWrapper` might be seen as something like a save() provider in this scenario `ItemWithSave`.
- To reflect a more real world scenario there is now also a "item is saving" state and the other id that's only used in the `save()` function.

The final code (also see: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-shape-k66wy?file=/src/App.js).

### Intial state, items from server

```
const itemsFromServer = {
  "1": {
    id: "1",
    otherIdForSavingOnly: "1-1",
    value: "test",
    isSaving: false
  },
  "2": {
    id: "2",
    otherIdForSavingOnly: "2-2",
    value: "another row",
    isSaving: false
  }
};
```

### A reducer to manage state

```
function reducer(currentItems, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_VALUE":
      return {
        ...currentItems,
        [action.id]: {
          ...currentItems[action.id],
          value: action.value
        }
      };

    case "START_SAVE":
      return {
        ...currentItems,
        [action.id]: {
          ...currentItems[action.id],
          isSaving: true
        }
      };

    case "STOP_SAVE":
      return {
        ...currentItems,
        [action.id]: {
          ...currentItems[action.id],
          isSaving: false
        }
      };

    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

### Our `ItemList` to render all items from the server

```
export default function ItemList() {
  const [items, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, itemsFromServer);

  return (
    <ItemListDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <ul>
        {Object.values(items).map(item => (
          <ItemWrapper key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </ItemListDispatch.Provider>
  );
}
```

### The main solution `ItemWrapper` or `ItemWithSave`

```
function ItemWrapper({ item }) {
  const dispatch = useContext(ItemListDispatch);

  const handleSave = useCallback(
    // Could be extracted entirely
    async function save() {
      if (item.value.length < 5) {
        alert("Incorrect length.");
        return;
      }

      dispatch({ type: "START_SAVE", id: item.id });

      // Save to API
      // eg. this will use otherId that's not necessary for the Item component
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

      dispatch({ type: "STOP_SAVE", id: item.id });
    },
    [item, dispatch]
  );

  return (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      value={item.value}
      isSaving={item.isSaving}
      onSave={handleSave}
    />
  );
}
```

### Our `Item`

```
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ id, value, isSaving, onSave }) {
  const dispatch = useContext(ItemListDispatch);

  console.log("render", id);

  if (isSaving) {
    return <li>Saving...</li>;
  }

  function onChange(event) {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_VALUE", id, value: event.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <li>
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <button onClick={onSave}>Save</button>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question I'd like to ask : is it really a problem to re-render ?

You are right that react will re-call every render for every function you have here, but your DOM should not change that much it might not be a big deal.

If you have heavy calculation while rendering `Item`, then you can memoize the heavy calculations.

If you really want to optimize this code, I see different solutions here:

1. Simplest solution : change the `ItemList` to a class component, this way handleSave will be an instance method.
2. Use an external form library that should work fine: you have powerfull form libraries in [final-form](https://final-form.org/react), [formik](https://formik.org/) or [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/)
3. Another external library : you can try [recoiljs](https://recoiljs.org/) that has been build for this specific use-case

Comment: Valid question. In this case I assume it's a problem to re-render. Your option 1 might indeed be the best way then? And so there is no real elegant solution by using hooks + function components?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you find out, I may be interested too :)

Comment: I've added another answer of how I handle it now, might be helpful (also a bit more complex).

Answer (score 0):

Wow this was fun! Hooks are very different then classes.  I got it to work by changing your Item component.

```
const Item = React.memo(
  function Item({ id, value, onChange, onSave }) {
    console.log("render", id);

    return (
      <li>
        <input
          value={value}
          onChange={event => onChange(id, event.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => onSave(id)}>Save</button>
      </li>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    // console.log("PrevProps", prevProps);
    // console.log("NextProps", nextProps);
    return prevProps.value === nextProps.value;
  }
);
```

By adding the second parameter to React.memo it only updates when the value prop changes.  The docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) explain that this is the equivalent of shouldComponentUpdate in classes.

I am not an expert at Hooks so anyone who can confirm or deny my logic, please chime in and let me know but I think that the reason this needs to be done is because the two functions declared in the body of the ItemList component (handleChange and handleSave) are in fact changing on each render.  So when the map is happening, it passes in new instances each time for handleChange and handleSave.  The Item component detects them as changes and causes a render.  By passing the second parameter you can control what the Item component is testing and only check for the value prop being different and ignore the onChange and onSave.

There might be a better Hooks way to do this but I am not sure how.  I updated the code sample so you can see it working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-roentgen-5f25f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While in this case this solution would work, it's quite prone to hard-to-find bugs in more complex real world scenarios. 

When for example when each item has an `otherValue` prop, we change this `otherValue` outside of the Item component and we read `otherValue` in the `handleSave()` function, it would have an incorrect + outdated result. This is because the `handleSave()` function is still from the latest render, not the most actual version.

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I agree, I don't think this is the best solution due to the facts you pointed out .  I even stated that I am not a Hooks expert but I can't see a different way to do it and not get the extra re-renders.  I am really hoping someone will post an answer that will solve this problem in a pure hooks way or confirm that Julien's is the valid way.  If this were classes and the two functions (Save and Change) were instance/static my guess is it would not cause a re-render but that means they have to be classes and not hooks :(